# Ubuntu accepts wifi only when booted without the laptop charger (DELL PRECISION M5520)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, dell, battery

I run a dualboot (Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10) in my DELL PRECISION M5520 laptop. The first preference to boot is Ubuntu.

Its a weird thing that I found. Whenever I boot to ubuntu with my laptop charger, Ubuntu will not be able to connect to the wifi. The Ubuntu OS behaves as if there were no wifi modem for the laptop. But only when I boot Ubuntu without connecting the Laptop charger, I am able to access the wifi option.

Also it is to be noted whether I boot to Windows 10 with or without the laptop charger , I am able to access the wifi options ..

Also I have checked the UEFI settings and I dont see an option anywhere that would sort this weird issue which I have only with Ubuntu and not with Windows 10.

Looking forward for some suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you not asked this before?

Comment: yeah .. Not exatly but Kind of .. And I thought the problem was somewhere else ... Didnt know before that the laptop charger would cause this issue